# Why am I getting this error in build.gradle in my Flutter Project in Android Studio?

Tags: firebase, flutter, build.gradle

I have added the Project-level build.gradle dependencies and also App-level build.gradle dependencies in my Flutter Project inorder to connect to Firebase. But then, I see errors and I don't see any Firebase connection messages while running. Where did it go wrong? What have I done? Please check the screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't depend on screenshots of text.  Copy the text into the question itself so it's easy to read, copy, and search.  Add a screenshot if you think that also helps, but the text should appear in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The highlight error on the build.grade can be ignored since you are not running it as an android project.

What you need to pay attention to is any errors, if any, on the Run tab at the bottom of the screen.

Just continue following the process and add the **google-services.json** file onto your app folder, since I cannot see it on the screenshot, meaning Firebase is still not fully set up.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate that :D